# Web view page is empty if clicks the back arrow in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have a `WebView` page with multiple links. By clicking the links it will open another `WebView` page with a close button. If I click the close button, the current window should close and the `WebView` page should not reload. I tried using `onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop()` but it shows `WebView` page as empty. Please help to resolve this.

```
class Leader extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(children: <Widget>[
        WebView(
          initialUrl: 'web view url',
          javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
          navigationDelegate: (NavigationRequest request) {
            print(request.url);
            var url = request.url;
            Navigator.pushReplacement(context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => WebView2(urlVal: url)));
            return NavigationDecision.navigate;
          },
        ),
      ]),
    );
  }
}

class WebView2 extends StatefulWidget {
  final String urlVal;
  WebView2({Key key, @required this.urlVal}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _WebView2State createState() => _WebView2State();
}

class _WebView2State extends State<WebView2> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
          body: Stack(children: <Widget>[
        SimplePdfViewerWidget(
          completeCallback: (bool result) {
            print("completeCallback,result:${result}");
          },
          initialUrl: widget.urlVal,
        ),
        Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            child: SizedBox(
              width: 330,
              child: RaisedButton(
                  onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
                  child: const Text('Close', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)),
                  textColor: Colors.white,
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  elevation: 5),
            ))
      ])),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: @SelimKundakçıoğlu i have added the code. Please check

Answer (score 15):

You are using `Navigator.pushReplacement()` in your first `WebView` widget. So when you try to pop the second `WebView` there are no widgets to show. Instead of using `Navigator.pushReplacement()` try to use `Navigator.push()`

Answer (score 3):

Try in this method of `Navigator.pushReplacement`

```js
Navigator.pushReplacement<void>(
  context,
  MaterialPageRoute<void>( builder: (_) => ViewScreen()),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use return after navigator push

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(children: [
        WebView(
          initialUrl: 'web view url',
          javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
          navigationDelegate: (NavigationRequest request) {
            print(request.url);
            var url = request.url;
            Navigator.pushReplacement(context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => WebView2(urlVal: url)));
            ;
          },
        ),
      ]),
    );
  }
}
```